# Parsing a lot of XML files in parallel

Tags: c#, database, parallel-processing, xml-parsing, parallel.foreach

I have 2 million XML files that I need to parse by specified xpath statement and write the result into a database table.

I established following workflow:

Take XML file from disks

Parse into XMLDocument class.

Parse data into DataTable class according to provided XPath expression.

Flush DataTable to SQL server via SqlBulkCopy class

This worklfow is executed via parallel foreach.
Unfortunately the parsing of one file is very fast so the bottle kneck is clearly the writing to SQL server. So I thought about collecting the data in memory and only flush it when a certain threshold is reached.

New bottle kneck is the serialization then because I end up with mall DataTable objects that need to merge into a bigger one. This merge needs to be thread safe of course. So I end up with the same througput and the all 8 could cores are only 35% in use.

Is there any idea how to get more throughout and stress the CPU more?

Comment: Why do you need to "parse into XMLDocument"?  You just create a new XMLDocument object pointed at the file.

Comment: See msdn article : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/usisvde/2009/10/24/how-to-get-started-with-multi-core-parallel-processing-you-can-use/

Comment: The XML is gzipped that's why I stated 2 seperate steps. I also tried using async bulk copy but it closed the connection although I didn't dispose it

Comment: Is it possible to sort your input files by size before processing?  If you could batch process at approximately the same speed, it should be more efficient to minimise your wait and merge the result into an appropriate bulk import size for SQL